# Exception finding a layout file

Tags: android

I keep getting google play crash reports with FileNotFoundException exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/layout/newday.xml
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:533)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2132)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2105)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
at com.mycompany.myapp.activities.NewDayActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:75)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My app's package is com.mycompany.myapp. This does not happen very often. Also users that are complaining about this issue say that this happens in 50% of cases. What could be wrong with that?

In activity, i use this method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.newbodymeasureday);
}
```

in super.onCreate(arg0) I have have this

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

and I also have a theme changing in this super call

```
String theme = SharedPrefsUtils.getCustomTheme(act);
String[] codes = act.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.themes_codes);
if (theme != null && theme.equals(codes[1])) {
    act.setTheme(R.style.GymGymTheme);
    Log.d(TAG, "Theme Light");
}
```

Comment: we need also see some Java code.

Comment: *DO* you have the layout file res/layout/newday.xml in your application package?

Comment: can you group the users into "only with this android version/device"? If so on which api/device does this happen?

Comment: Axarydax. yes, exactly. It's in res/layout/newday.xml.

Comment: Sajmon, updated my answer

Comment: WarrenFaith. i will try to analyze all of my reports

Comment: I think this may happen due to `OutOfMemory`

Comment: Ovidiu Latcu, why do you think so? Do you have any reference that could prove that?